# Arabic Text Encrypt and Decrypt add into Server

Tags: php, android, mysql

Problem for Arabic Text Encrypt and Decrypt add into Server that time not decrypted particular arabic text. But the text saved below format

Ã™Â†Ã˜Â¸Ã˜Â§Ã™Â… Ã™Â…Ã˜Â¨Ã™ÂŠÃ˜Â¹Ã˜Â§Ã˜Âª Ã˜Â±Ã˜Â§...

How to solve this problem.

Comment: what is actual text?

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: Arabic Text is : نظام مبيعات راج انفوتك 
English Text : Raj Retail POS

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **MySQL** then please change `collation` type of that field to **utf8_general_ci** and then save data. Problem will get solved.

Comment: check this: http://demo.phpmyadmin.net/master-config/tbl_structure.php?db=arabic&table=arabic&token=f4a54c4dc37d95b2ce3bb8db1859c91b @Senthilkumar you can check structure and browse

Comment: If we insert the Arabic text directly it works fine... But if we encrypt and decrypt the Arabic text in program wise it will be save like this format. (Ã™Â†Ã˜Â¸Ã˜Â§Ã™Â… Ã™Â…Ã˜Â¨Ã™ÂŠÃ˜Â¹Ã˜Â§Ã˜Âª Ã˜Â±Ã˜Â§)

Comment: why did you need to do that process?

Comment: i don't think to do that process.. just do as simple as

Comment: i have send all data encrypt and decrypt method. but its work fine english text and numbers. but not work correctly in arabic text.

Comment: Hi, I think u save arabic text directly in server. if u used encryption or decryption?

Comment: you can simply direct save the data using php script too

Comment: how did you encrypt/decrypt data?